# Is there a way to get the underlying HTML code of a selected area?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The content management system I wrote for our site uses a bookmarklet to post articles, which reads the selected area on a page with document.getSelection(). But in some cases it would be very useful to read the underlying HTML code for the selected area as well, to get links and other HTML formatting.

Anyone know of a jQuery plugin or other Javascript technique to access the raw HTML that produces a selected area?

Comment: `document.getSelection` returns the selection along with any HTML that spans only a part of the selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as you said, get the [selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/selection)

```
var sel = document.getSelection();
```

This does have some details about selected nodes, too, but if you want to do more then convert this to a [range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/range) (If `.rangeCount > 1` you may want to loop here)

```
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
```

Next, using `range.commonAncestorContainer` and `range.startContainer` walk through the DOM tree performing whatever you want until you reach `range.endContainer`.
All of these nodes should be in the selection.

---

Here is some code that'll return all (top level) selected nodes and, optionally, apply a callback to **every** node in selection.

```
function selectedNodes(callback, context) {
    var sel = document.getSelection(),
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0),
        indices = [],
        nextNode = function nextNode(e) {
            if (e.childNodes.length > 0) return e.childNodes[0];
            while(!e.nextSibling && e.parentNode) e = e.parentNode;
            return e.nextSibling;
        },
        e = range.startContainer;
    if (callback) {
        callback.call(context, e);
        while(e !== range.endContainer) {
            e = nextNode(e);
            callback.call(context, e);
        }
        e = range.startContainer;
    }
    if (e === range.commonAncestorContainer) return [e];
    else {
        while (e !== range.commonAncestorContainer) {
            indices[0] = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(e.parentNode.childNodes, e);
            e = e.parentNode;
        }
        e = range.endContainer;
        while (e !== range.commonAncestorContainer) {
            indices[1] = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(e.parentNode.childNodes, e);
            e = e.parentNode;
        }
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(e.childNodes, indices[0], indices[1]+1);
    }
}

/*
selectedNodes(console.log, console);
node1
..
nodeN
[node1, .., nodeM] // only top-level
*/
```

Comment: Forget all those complicated stuff and use [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) by [Tim Down](http://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down) :D

Comment: Actually Rangy is kind of popular among people who always works with selections and ranges.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! And I will definitely check out Rangy - hadn't heard of it before.