# jQuery: Regex testing a comment node

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, testing, nodes

I want to test if comments end with ***g**, a certain pattern I'm working on to remove redundant comments.

Here is what I have until now:

```
   $('body', $content).contents().each(function() {
        if(this.nodeType == 8 ){
            var value = this.nodeValue;
            console.log(/(([\s\S])*? \*g)/.test(value))
        }
    });
```

However, I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error on the test.

I'd appreciate some help.

---

**Solved:**

**Problem:** Testing pattern was incorrect.

**Correct pattern:**   `regexp.test(string);`

Comment: If you want to match `*g` literally you need to escape the asterisk `\*g` since in regex it's a quantifier

Comment: Hi HamZa. Thank you for the heads up. I still get the error, though.

Comment: Could you provide a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? I'm no expert in javascript, but it would help to debug your issue. Also, did you forget a semicolon `;` after `console.log(value.test(/(([\s\S])*? \*g)/))`?

Comment: Yes I did. However in JS it isn't essential. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/37wkt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What browsers are you aiming at? *IE9+* can use a [*TreeWalker*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.createTreeWalker)

```
var t = document.createTreeWalker(document, NodeFilter.SHOW_COMMENT),
    e;
while (e = t.nextNode()) { // iterate over comments
    if (/\*g$/.test(e.nodeValue)) { // whatever test you want to do
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

You can implement a walker yourself, which I have done before in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13665941/1615483) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21579859/1615483) but it can get complicated :(

---

Started writing a polyfill/shim for *TreeWalker*, `document.createTreeWalker` and *NodeFilter*, lots missing but as is it gives you more than what you need for what I used above

```
if (!window.TreeWalker) {
    window.TreeWalker = (function () {
        function TreeWalker() {
            // pass
        }
        return TreeWalker;
    }());
}
if (!document.createTreeWalker) { // assuming TreeWalker
    document.createTreeWalker = (function () {
        var Constructor = TreeWalker;
        try { // Illegal construction workaround
            new Constructor();
        } catch (e) {
            Constructor = function TreeWalker() {};
            Constructor.prototype = TreeWalker.prototype;
        }
        function nextNode() {
            var e = this.currentNode;
            if (e === null) {
                e = this.root;
                if (this.whatToShow & Math.pow(2, e.nodeType - 1))
                    return this.currentNode = e;
            }
            while (1) {
                while (e.firstChild) {
                    e = e.firstChild;
                    if (this.whatToShow & Math.pow(2, e.nodeType - 1))
                        return this.currentNode = e;
                }
                while (!e.nextSibling && e.parentNode !== this.root) {
                    e = e.parentNode;
                }
                if (!e.nextSibling && e.parentNode === this.root) // reached end
                    return null; // none left
                e = e.nextSibling;
                if (this.whatToShow & Math.pow(2, e.nodeType - 1))
                    return this.currentNode = e;
            }
        }
        function previousSibling() {
            if (this.currentNode.previousSibling)
                return this.currentNode = this.currentNode.previousSibling;
            return null;
        }
        function nextSibling() {
            if (this.currentNode.nextSibling)
                return this.currentNode = this.currentNode.nextSibling;
            return null;
        }
        function createTreeWalker(root, whatToShow, filter, entityReferenceExpansion) {
            var t = new Constructor();
            // root
            t.root = root || document;
            // whatToShow
            if (whatToShow === 0)
                t.whatToShow = 0;
            else // -1 | 0
                t.whatToShow = (whatToShow | 0) || 0xFFFFFFFF;
            // todo: filter
            t.filter = filter || null;
            // todo: entityReferenceExpansion
            t.entityReferenceExpansion = entityReferenceExpansion || null;
            // currentNode
            t.currentNode = root;
            // nextNode
            t.nextNode = nextNode;
            // todo: previousNode
                /* test for previousSibling before parentNode
                 * if previousSibling, keep doing lastChild until no more
                 * test against whatToShow
                */
            // todo: parentNode
            // todo: firstChild
            // todo: lastChild
            // previousSibling
            t.previousSibling = previousSibling;
            // nextSibling
            t.nextSibling = nextSibling;
            // return
            return t;
        }
        return createTreeWalker;
    }());
}
if (!window.NodeFilter) {
    window.NodeFilter = (function () {
        function NodeFilter() {
            // pass
        }
        NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT = 1;
        NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT = 2;
        NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP = 3;
        NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL = -1;
        NodeFilter.SHOW_ATTRIBUTE = 2;
        NodeFilter.SHOW_CDATA_SECTION = 8;
        NodeFilter.SHOW_COMMENT = 128;
        NodeFilter.SHOW_DOCUMENT = 256;
        NodeFilter.SHOW_DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT = 1024;
        NodeFilter.SHOW_DOCUMENT_TYPE = 512;
        NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT = 1;
        NodeFilter.SHOW_ENTITY = 32;
        NodeFilter.SHOW_ENTITY_REFERENCE = 16;
        NodeFilter.SHOW_NOTATION = 2048;
        NodeFilter.SHOW_PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION = 64;
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT = 4;
        return NodeFilter;
    }());
}
```

Comment: I'll be using this for a commercial plugin so I'd prefer a solution where IE8 works. But still, thank you for the suggestion!